# Close form currently in focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering how you would close the Form that is currently in focus or the one which a control is contained in. For example, I have an imported header with a menu that I import into all forms in my application.

This is the (simplified) code in my Header class:

```cs
public static Panel GetHeader()
{
    ...
    menuItem.Text = "Menu Item";
    menuItem.Name = "Next form to open";
    menuItem.Click += toolStrip_Click;
    ...
}

public static void toolStrip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
    NavigationClass.SaveNextForm(menuItem.Name);
}
```

The navigation class is just something I made which will select the next form to open but I couldn't find anything to then close the current one (since Close() isn't an option due to it being imported with Controls.Add(HeaderClass.GetHeader))

**Edit**

Just to make clear, this form is in another file which is just a normal class file. That's where the difficulty lies because I'm trying to avoid a severe violation of the DRY principle

Comment: is there a `Parent` or `Container` property you coud use?

Comment: Don't make the event handler *static* and it is simply `this.Close()`.  Not the only reason to avoid it, static events are very risky since they add a reference to the form object.  Explicitly unsubscribing the event is very important to avoid the leak, everybody forgets that.  "don't do it" is the only good advice.

Comment: Nah, when I put this.Close() into it, there's just an error since it isn't a form class, just a normal one. It merely gets the header and footer so in the Form_Load() function, I just do Controls.Add(Header.GetHeader()). Or should I be using it as a form class or something similar? And the static part, do you mean just generally don't use static normally or just in the form?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote an answer or comment if you find it useful.

Comment: Can't at the moment. I need to get 15 reputation first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use static handlers as @Hans Passant suggests. That is important.

Try sending your main form to your class as a parameter, and store it in that class. This can be done either when you are instantiating your class, or after that. Then, when you need to close the form, call it's `Close` method. Since you don't include your codes in more details, here is my example with some assumptions.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private HeaderClass HeaderClass;
    public MainForm()
    {
        HeaderClass = new HeaderClass(this);
    }
}

public class HeaderClass
{
    private MainForm MainForm;
    public HeaderClass(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        MainForm = mainForm;
    }

    public void MethodThatYouNeedToCloseTheFormFrom()
    {
        ...
        MainForm.Close();
        ...
    }
}
```

Let us know if you require any more elaboration.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it working though I did modify certain parts. Essentially this header/footer was something I could add to any of my forms and they would all come from one source (so easy editing). With the navigation class it opens the specific forms and I made it so it takes in the next form and returns the modified version (with a header). Thanks for the help